# Fetch data from Oracle database from past two hours?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to fetch data from an Oracle database from between two hours ago and `currentime_stamp`. How can I do that?

```
select count(*) as "trn<5",ROUND(avg (RESPONSE_TIME),2) as avr,ssn 
    from db_activity a 
    where a.REQ_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN current_timestamp -2 AND current_timestamp
 group by ssn
```

Comment: Use sysdate to get current value. `where a.REQ_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN SYSDATE - (2/24) AND SYSDATE`

Answer (score 1):

When you work with `TIMESTAMP` you should better use `INTERVAL`:

```
select count(*) as "trn<5",ROUND(avg (RESPONSE_TIME),2) as avr,ssn 
    from db_activity a 
    where a.REQ_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN current_timestamp - INTERVAL '2' HOUR AND current_timestamp
group by ssn
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...where a.REQ_TIMESTAMP  >= (SYSDATE-1/12)
```